# Hyperledger fabric channel creation through node sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to create channel through hyperledger fabric node sdk but getting following errors.

Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.25.0.1:34196 because of error: error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'arun1', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

Here is my Nodes method

```
try {
    console.log("api hit");
    // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

    // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
    const userExists = await wallet.exists('user2');

    if (!userExists) {
        console.log('An identity for the user "user2" does not exist in the wallet');
        console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
        return;
    }

    // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
    const gateway = new Gateway();

    await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user2', discovery: { enabled: false, asLocalhost: true } });
    var client = gateway.getClient()

    // first read in the file, this gives us a binary config envelope
    let envelope_bytes = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..','..','..','fabric-samples/first-network/channel-artifacts/channel1.tx'));
    let adminKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..','..','..','fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/pem.key'));
    let adminCert = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..','..','..','fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem'));
    client.setAdminSigningIdentity(adminKey.toString(),adminCert.toString(),"Org1MSP")
    console.log(`admin key=====   ${adminKey}`);
    console.log(`admin cert=====   ${adminCert}`);
    // have the nodeSDK extract out the config update
    var signatures = new Array();

    var config_update = client.extractChannelConfig(envelope_bytes);
    var configSignature=client.signChannelConfig(config_update)

    signatures.push(configSignature);
    // create an orderer object to represent the orderer of the network
    var orderer=client.getOrderer("orderer.example.com") 
    let request = {
        config: config_update, //the binary config
        signatures: signatures, // the collected signatures
        name: 'arun1', // the channel name
        orderer: orderer, //the orderer from above
        txId: client.newTransactionID(true) //the generated transaction id
    };
    console.log(`configupdate${config_update}`);

    // this call will return a Promise
    console.log("Transaction sent 2");
    const result = await client.createChannel(request)
    return {
        status: 200,
        data: {
            data: JSON.parse(result.toString())
        }
    };

} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to evaluate transaction: ${error}`);
    //  process.exit(1);
    return {
        status: 400,
        data: {
            data: `${error}`
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my connection.json

```
    {
    "name": "first-network-org1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/home/arun/Hyperledger_1.4.2/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/pem.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/home/arun/Hyperledger_1.4.2/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]

        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.example.com"
            }
        }

    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca-org1",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the error my path to the admincert was wrong

```
    let adminCert = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..','..','..','fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem'));
```

Replaced the cacerts with admincerts

```
    let adminCert = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..','..','..','fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/admincerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a problem with the Fabric security, rather than with your code.

How is your Fabric setup, are you using an 'old' copy of configtx.yaml?  I don't know when it changed, but in the configtx.yaml you now need to specify channel policies, so you will need a line such as `<<: *ChannelDefaults` under your profiles section in the file.  So for example:

```
Profiles:

ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
        Capabilities:
            <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Consortiums:
        constrade:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
ThreeOrgsChannel:
    Consortium: constrade
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
            - *Org3
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

and you will obviously need the policies defined in the `ChannelDefaults` section of your file.

The latest first-network sample in fabric-samples has the correct file format.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error response, it is rejecting because you are not passing the admin creds while creating new channel.

Its a fabric channel writers policy, only admins can create channel

```
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/arun/Hyperledger_1.4.2/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/pem.key
```

are you sure pem.key ?